# Pivot table with two headers in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I'd soo appreciate if someone could help.

My initial table looks like this:

```
Brand       Period_1    Period_1  Period_2   Period_2
------------------------------------------------------
             New York    London    New York   London
------------------------------------------------------
BrandName_1  123,45     233,23     232,23    393,23
BrandName_2  139,45     202,63     939,38    399,00
```

I would like to make a pivot table that should look like this:

```
           Brand        Period_1   Period_2
New York
           BrandName_1   123,45    232,23
           BrandName_2   139,45    939,38
London
           BrandName_1   233,23    393,23
           BrandName_2   202,63    399,00
```

How can I achieve it in Excel?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a flat table with these columns and one item per row

city, brand name, Period, amount

Then you can build this pivot table. You won't be able to build it from the table that is already structured like a report.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to convert table into a flat one, other than manually? Maybe use unpivot?

Comment: with the two levels of headers that won't be so easy. You could copy the table underneath again, add a column for the period, quickly fill in the data, remove the now superfluous columns and headers and then you can unpivot.